# multiple update data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have data

```
id_service = 1,  service_order= "3000" 
id_service = 2,  service_order= "4000"
```

I have input data that I will fill with different values, I do multiple updates
but I have an error which is:

```
Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' UPDATE service SET charges_order = WHERE array id_service = '1'
```

how to overcome this?

> mycontroller

```
public function update($id_service)
{
    foreach ($this->input->post('charges_order') as $data) {
        $data = array(
            'charges_order' => $this->input->post('charges_order')
        );
        // echo '<pre>', print_r($data);
        $this->M_report->update($id_service, $data);
        redirect('backend/report');
    }
}
```

mymodel

```
public function update($id_service,$invoice){
    $this->db->where('id_service', $id_service);
    $this->db->update('service', $invoice);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // you can delete all data and then use add query:like this:
//controller
      $this->M_report->delete($id_service);
     foreach ($this->input->post('charges_order') as $data) {
            $data = array(
                'charges_order' => $this->input->post('charges_order')
            );
            // echo '<pre>', print_r($data);
            $this->M_report->add($id_service, $data);
            redirect('backend/report');
        }
    //model
    function delete($id_service){
    return $this->db->where('id',$id_service)->delete();
    }
    function add($data) {
            if ($this->db->insert('table_name', $data) > 0) {
                return $this->db->insert_id();
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: delete will delete all data which is relate to this id and new record will add.